# Feign: Spring cannot autowire @FeignClient bean in jar file

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

I have `@FeignClient` declaration in `ea.jar`:

```
@FeignClient(name = "ea")
public interface AdvertGroupRemoteService {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/group/{groupId}")
    AdvertGroupVO findByGroupId(@PathVariable("groupId") Integer adGroupId);
}
```

I added this jar as a maven dependency, then inject it:

```
@RestController
public class TestCtr {

    @Autowired
    private AdvertGroupRemoteService advertGroupRemoteService;
}
```

I always got `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private cn.com.sina.alan.ms.ea.api.service.AdvertGroupRemoteService cn.com.sina.alan.gateway.controller.TestCtr.advertGroupRemoteService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [cn.com.sina.alan.ms.ea.api.service.AdvertGroupRemoteService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [cn.com.sina.alan.ms.ea.api.service.AdvertGroupRemoteService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

But, if I move the `@FeignClient` declaration into same project(not added as jar dependency), this exception is gone.

I have no idea about this, help

Comment: Sounds like your classpath scanning of annotations in Spring does not include the package that your FeignClient is in.

Comment: @gregwhitaker It's not the package problem. I found this link helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241198/error-injecting-feignclient-from-another-project

Comment: Did that other question solve your problem?

Comment: @ShawnClark Yes, it did. But I don't know why

Comment: @Neo `@EnableFeignClients`, by default, only scans the package hierarchy of the class it is used on. To scan outside of the package you have to be explicit.

Comment: @spencergibb Thanks, got it